# install python script on windows

Tags: python, windows

I try to install python script on Windows. In the Readme file there is these indications :

```
cd pattern-2.6
python setup.py install
```

But I think that these instructions are for Linux. How can I install it on windows?

Thank you

Comment: It's the same command as long as python is on your path.

Comment: `cd` is for the windows command prompt

Comment: @WhatsThePoint `cd` is also for Linux.

Comment: @SiHa didnt know that, not sure why OP thinks this is only for linux though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Python are you using?  If it is recent, it will have shipped with pip.  If so, open a command window/python prompt(as an administrator) then try:

```
pip install pattern
```

If pip is not installed a cursory google will tell you how to get that.  Hope this helps.

Comment: gotta love pip :D